# using abstract private methods as an interface

Tags: python, oop, interface

Suppose I have a base class which represents some interface

```
class Parser(object):

    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

    @abstractmethod
    def _parse(self, text):
        """Internal interface. This is somethig a potential
        user must implement for his own implementation of Parser"""

        pass

    def add_quotes(self, text):
        """some postprocessing. Say, every parser should have quotes"""
        # ...

    def parse(self, text):
        """External interface. Whoever uses children of Parser will
        use this method"""

        return self.add_quotes(self._parse(text))
```

Is it ok to use private methods for "internal" API (i.e. make users override private methods for interface implementation) and normal methods for external usage? This seems a bit odd... I see a couple of alternative approaches but don't know which one is better:

- use metaclass to "wrap" overriden methods with certain postprocessing. An advantage would be having a single name for internal and external interfaces
- having synonimous names, e.g. `preparse` and `parse` for internal and external methods respectively
- Leave the responsibility of adding quotes to all implementations of the interface and ensure this with tests. But this approach seems much less safe

Comment: "primarily opinion-based" IMHO. And really there's no one-size-fits-all answer to this...

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers A cons and pros style of answer to this would be very valuable, wouldn't it? Or maybe there are some "don't ever do"'s to some of the listed approaches?